# Output layer doesn't have activation function in custom estimator

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

In the [custom estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators), output layer doesn't have activation.

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['n_classes'], activation=None)
```

then using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` to calculate loss

```
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
```

### Questions

1. In general, output layer should also have activation function?
2. `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` means using softmax as activation
   function of the output layer when calculate the loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the softmax and the cross entropy based on it "naively" can be numerically unstable. This is why it is recommended *not* to have an activation in your output layer (usually it would be `tf.nn.softmax` for classification). Instead, Tensorflow supplies loss functions such as `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` which apply the softmax internally (in a numerically stable fashion) and then compute the cross entropy based on that. That is, you are supposed to supply model outputs *without* your own softmax (commonly called **logits**).

E.g. in the [API docs for the softmax op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2) you can usually find passages such as

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.